# WPF - Specialized image display for 16 bit depth grayscale monitors

Tags: c#, wpf, opencv, directx

I am currently developing an application to display 16 bit grayscale images to a 16 bit grayscale compatible monitor.
Most of my experience in software development has been in WPF. However I am reading that even though WPF can accept Gray16 type images, they are internally converted to 32 bit color.
In pursuit of this, I have been using the WPFDXInterop https://github.com/microsoft/WPFDXInterop/ to try and output the image as I want though a DirectX 11 based custom control, and use CUDA and OpenCV at times for image processing.

Am I out of luck in using WPF for this situation? Do I need to change coding environments?
It has been important to me to be able to continue using CUDA and OpenCV for the image processing, but I can change from DirectX to OpenGL is I have to, and learn something other than WPF.

Comment: From further research into this, it seems possible that I could instead develop as UWP, and use their SwapChainPanel with DirectX rendertarget. And then for GPU programming use DirectCompute. I will know for sure if this is a viable solution when I start writing it.

Comment: Even more research into this, I should be able to import UWP controls like SwapChainPanel into WPF via the "VisualLayer" as seen at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/using-the-visual-layer-with-wpf

Comment: I have implemented the initial pieces of a working solution to this. I have used https://github.com/marb2000/XamlIslands/tree/master/1903_Samples/WPF_Core3_App as a a reference for how to accomplish my goals, to much success. I now use UWP's SwapChainPanel and create my own textures via DirectX11 for use in OpenCV and CUDA GPGPU methods. I am also confident the output image bit depth with be correct because I am creating the swapchain and devices myself.

Comment: What's your monitor model?